# Quarkus with Panache getting hibernate error HHH000183

Tags: java, hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I built an application with Quarkus and I'm using Hibernate with Panache for the models. Everything goes well, the application starts, but when I call a webservice to get a list using Panache functionalities (`.listAll()`), I get an empty list and I see the following message in the console:

```
HHH000183: no persistent classes found for query class: from com.myproject.model.TeamEntity
```

My models are defined with `@Entity` annotations that should allow Hibernate to find by itself the entity mappings. Here is an example with the `Team` model:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEAM")
public class TeamEntity extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "TEAM_SEQ_GEN")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TEAM_SEQ_GEN", sequenceName = "TEAM_SEQ", allocationSize = 10)
    @Column(name = "ID_TEAM", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    ...

}
```

I don't have any `persistence.xml` file in the project, only the `application.properties` linked with Quarkus. Here are the relevant properties extracted from mine:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:/@MYWALLET
%dev.quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:MYUSER/MYPASSWORD@localhost:1521/SAA
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=2
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=10
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.new-connection-sql=alter session set current_schema=MYSCHEMA
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

Does someone know where the problem could come from ? Hibernate should detect entities with annotations and use them in queries automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came out that the problem was on Quarkus Datasource configuration in the `application.properties` file. More particularly from this specific line to define the schema used at first connection (I  have to admit that was not good looking):

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.new-connection-sql=alter session set current_schema=MYSCHEMA
```

Replacing the line above with the following solved the problem:

```
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.default-schema=MYSCHEMA
```

In conclusion, I think Hibernate cannot find / does not take the entities defined if this property is not defined, maybe because it makes some kind of detection beforehand. That's only a supposition, if someone knows more precisely how Hibernate works for that specific case, I would be very interested !